Do anti-neutrons actually annihilate in practice (since there are no attractive forces on them)?
I know that an anti-neutron will annihilate with a regular neutron. But consider this: there is no force acting at a distance on an anti-neutron. It's not charged so it won't get sucked into an electron, a proton, a neutron, or anything. Positrons and electrons will be attracted and run into each other and annihilate. Same with protons and anti-protons. But an anti-neutron is basically not attracted to anything. So when an anti-proton is zooming through space, it can only hit a neutron by accident. But matter is 99.99999999...% empty space, so accidentally hitting a neutron seems super unlikely.
Does that mean that, in practical terms, anti-neutrons don't really get annihilated?

you are forgetting that  antineutrons  should  also decay, as do neutrons. search "decays of antineutron"

I'm a bit surprised to see votes to close as unclear. The question seems clear to me. An antineutron fired into a solid is unlikely to hit a nucleus since the nucleus is only a femtometre or so across, while an antiproton is more likely to hit a nucleus due to the electrostatic attraction between the antiproton and the nucleus. So in these circumstances is the antineutron less likely to annihilate?

The anti-neutron just like the neutron, should have a nonzero magnetic moment, so it can in theory interact electromagnetically as the neutron already can.

By your logic the cross sections for neutron interactions with nuclei would all be very small and fairly similar. Yet they vary widely and can be quite ‘large’. So, one interesting question is what the anti-neutron - nucleus interactions look like (resulting energy levels, Q values, etc.).

What exactly do you mean by "annihilation" of a $ n \bar{n}$ pair? Are you considering also $n \bar{n} \to \rm pions$? A reasonable question would be to ask for the cross section of  $n \bar{n} \to f$ for one or several specified final states $ f \ne n \bar{n}$. Your issue with absence of "attractive forces" is simply misleading.

This would be a reasonable question for a high school student. But your profile says you are a PhD student in Electrical Engineering at Stanford focusing mostly on data sciency things. I understand that some electrical engineers don't do circuits and such. Have you had any quantum mechanics?

@mmesser314 - I’m definitely not a nuclear physicist, but I doubt that the physics of interaction between (normal) nuclei with anti-neutrons is normally covered even at the PhD level.

I guess that did come out condescending. I have to admit I don't know anything particular about the cross section of a neutron either. I couldn't explain why it would be large. I was just wondering whether an answer should include the idea that anti neutrons aren't point particles. They are described by wave functions which can be extended. If an anti neutron's wave function overlaps that of a neutron in a nucleus, there is a chance of an interaction.

https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.102.075025 might be one place for those more skilled in the art to start? Or https://indico.cern.ch/event/1360892/contributions/5728699/attachments/2776071/4837968/231130_AD_Higuchi.pdf
